# Can you distribute filename lists corresponding to datasets that say "Do not distribute"?

Tags: licensing, data-ownership

I collected some additional annotations for a dataset with a "License for Non-Commercial Use". I now have a subset of the original dataset and would like to provide it to the community alongside a publication but realise I cannot (because of the license).

Would it be possible for me to provide a filename list alongside the publication and instruct users to download the original dataset at its source and use the filenames alongside it?

Comment: Could you write a script to extract the subset from the full database, and tell other people how to obtain the full data and how to run your script?

Comment: Are you providing the instructions to your users on how to obtain the legal version of the data, or is it an instruction manual on how to download an illicit version? Maybe it makes a difference legally.  In any case, this is more of a legal question/copyright issue and it's not about open source. So, Law SE is the place to go with this.